# Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cpu and cuda:0

Tags: python, pytorch

I cannot understand why this error keeps popping out.
I start specifying the device variable

```
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    device = torch.device("cuda")
    n_gpu = torch.cuda.device_count()
    torch.cuda.get_device_name(0)
else:
    device = torch.device("cpu")
```

The model is the following

```
class CNN(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, initial_num_channels, num_channels):
    '''
    Args:
    initial_num_channels (int): size of the incoming feature vector 
    num_classes (int): size of the output prediction vector 
    num_channels (int): constant channel size to use throughout network
    '''
    super(CNN, self).__init__()
    self.convnet = nn.Sequential( 
        
        nn.Conv1d(in_channels=initial_num_channels,
                  out_channels=num_channels, kernel_size=3),

        nn.ELU(),

        nn.Conv1d(in_channels=num_channels, out_channels=num_channels,
                  kernel_size=3, stride=2),

        nn.ELU(), 
        
        nn.Conv1d(in_channels=num_channels, out_channels=num_channels,
                  kernel_size=3, stride=2),

        nn.ELU(), 
        
        nn.Conv1d(in_channels=num_channels, out_channels=num_channels,
                  kernel_size=3),

        nn.ELU() )
    
    
def forward(self, x, apply_softmax=False):

    """The forward pass of the classifier
    
    Args:
        x (torch.Tensor): an input data tensor. 
            x.shape should be (batch, dataset._max_seq_length)
        apply_softmax (bool): a flag for the softmax activation
            should be false if used with the Cross Entropy losses
    Returns:
        the resulting tensor. tensor.shape should be (batch, num_classes)
    """
    
    # input tensor: batch_size x channels x signal_length
    x = self.convnet(x)

    # average through maxpooling
    x = F.avg_pool1d(x, kernel_size=3)
    x = F.dropout(x, p=0.1)

    # go back to 2 dimensions: batch_size x features
    x = x.view(x.size(dim=0), -1)

    # compute the input size of linear combination layer
    num_features = x.size(dim=1)

    # final linear comb layers
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(num_features, 100)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(100, 2) 
    
    # mlp classifier
    x = F.relu(F.dropout(self.fc1(x), p=0.1))
    x = self.fc2(x)

    if apply_softmax:
        x = F.softmax(x, dim=1)

    return x
```

Here I move it onto the GPU

```
epochs = 10
model = CNN(initial_num_channels=1, num_channels=256)
# model = MultilayerPerceptron(input_dim=MAX_LEN, hidden_dim=100, output_dim=2)
model = model.to(device)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
```

Finally I run the training loop

```
train_loss_set = []
executed = False

for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
    train_loop = tqdm(train_dataloader)

    model.train()

    train_steps = 0
    train_loss = 0

    for (idx,(train_input, train_label)) in enumerate(train_loop):

        # add dimension=1 in position 1 to have channels=1
        # ONLY FOR CNN
        train_input = torch.unsqueeze(train_input, 1)

        train_input = train_input.clone().detach().requires_grad_(True).to(device)
        train_label = train_label.clone().detach().to(device)
        train_output = model(train_input)
        loss = criterion(train_output, train_label)
        loss.backward()
        train_loss_set.append(loss.item())
        optimizer.step()
        model.zero_grad()

        train_steps += 1
        train_loss += loss.item()
        train_loss_set.append(loss.item())

    print("Train loss: {}".format(train_loss/train_steps))
```

The error is triggered during the forward pass of the model, hence I assume, the problem is related to the input. I tried either the classic assignment input = input.to(device) and also the "fancier" one (which you can see above)

Comment: It's great that you include the relevant code, but it would really help if you also included the error message. As of now, it's a little unclear what your error is and exactly where it occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `fc1` and `fc2` layers which you create in your `forward` function. These are only created when the model is called on an input, and are not moved to the GPU. To fix this, you can use:

```
self.fc1 = nn.Linear(num_features, 100, device=x.device)
self.fc2 = nn.Linear(100, 2, device=x.device)
```

The definition of `fc2` could also be moved to the `__init__` function to avoid recreating it each time.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I was struggling on this... Your comment is correct, I put the linear combinations within the forward because I need to compute at run time the size of the input channels

Comment: @valeriova96 This only fixes the error message, but _conceptually_ this is very likely not what you want: since you recreate the last two layers each time, you are also reinitializing them with random weights each time, so the last two layers do not get trained.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.fc1 = nn.Linear(num_features, 100, device=x.device)
self.fc2 = nn.Linear(100, 2, device=x.device)
```

It's the correct solution!

Or you can set your

```
device=torch.device('cpu')
```